# Is there any way to make a set of floats with tolerance and still O(1) lookup?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, floating-point, set, heap

I want to make a set of floating point numbers, but with a twist:

When testing if some float x is a member of the set s, I want the test to return true if s contains some float f such that

```
abs(x - f) < tol
```

In other words, if the set contains a number that is close to x, return true. Otherwise return false.

One way I thought of doing this is to store numbers in a heap rather than a hash set, and use an approximate equality rule to decide whether the heap contains a close number.

However, that would take log(N) time, which is not bad, but it would be nice to get O(1) if such an algorithm exists.

Does anyone have any ideas how this might be possible?

Comment: Round stored keys to a multiple of `tol`. Look up `x'`, `x' - tol` and `x'+tol` where `x'` is a search key rounded to a multiple of `tol`. It helps if `tol` is `2^n` where `n` is a (possibly negative) integer.

Comment: @n.m. it's O(1) but not quite accurate since if you're unlucky you can find a match within 2tol. You can map rounded key -> sorted list of keys, which is accurate but gives O(log n) if there's a heavily populated bucket.

Comment: That cannot find values in between the additional keys. Consider a heap containing the number 1.0, which in IEEE-754 single precision is 00111111100000000000000000000000. If tol = 1E-6 (approx 2**-17), that means I need to subtract approximately 00000000000000001111111 from the mantissa, then add 00000000000000001111111 to the mantissa, as well as all numbers in between. You can see that there are seven 1's on the right of the mantissa, so you would need to add 2 * (2**7 - 1) numbers to the set, approximately 256 numbers. I have to agree this is technically O(1) but overhead is a bit high.

Comment: 256x overhead might not sound so bad, but there are 2 more problems: 1) If you want tol to be 1E-3 instead of 1E-6, the number of adds increases by a factor of 1024, so now we're talking about > 256,000 adds for every number we care about 2) if you use double precision floats, this approach quickly becomes unusable.

Comment: @PaulHankin "you can find a match within 2tol" Discard matches you don't need. This is not too different from normal hash collisions. You just discard entries with the same hash but that are different from what you are looking for. This just increases the number of collisions. You can end up with all of your entries having the same hash, but this can happen with a normal hash table too.

Comment: @JamesStrieter Of course Nx256 is much worse than NlogN for all realistic N, but I have no idea where 256 comes from. Perhaps from "as well as all numbers in between" which is definitely not what you should do.

Comment: @n.m. 256 comes from my first comment, where I show how many adds you need to do to add 1.0 to the set with a tolerance of 1E-6.

Comment: Rather than store a set of f-p numbers, store a set of intervals of f-p numbers, centred on your original numbers, and +/- the tolerance for equality matching.  This will have no impact on the complexity of the search for membership, but might offer some useful improvement in the constant term(s).  At the expense of space and some pre-computation.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark that is a cool idea! Forgive my ignorance, but how would you find the closest bucket in O(1) time?

Comment: I need to store the number 1.0 (already rounded to a multiple of `tol` so no further action is needed) and absolutely nothing else. I don't know where this "all numbers in between" idea comes from. I never said or meant or suggested anything like that. You get a number to store, you round it to a multiple of `tol` and use that value as a key, and store the original number you've got with that key, and that's it. End of story.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark suggests almost exactly the same thing I do. Matt Timmermans also suggests almost the same thing, Finally your own idea of masking bits is also exactly the same thing.

Comment: You can't really have a (mathematically sound) "set", which replaces "equals" by "close to tolerance" -- because your equals operator needs to be transitive. However, you could have a set of (arbitrary) floating point numbers and check for an (arbitrary) `x` if there is a number close to `tol` in your set. Is `tol` always the same in your case? Is it a power of two? How large would it typically be compared to the relative accuracy of your floating point type?

Comment: You need to change the title of your question. There's perhaps an O(n) way to create the set, with each element requiring O(1). But I'm reasonably certain that there's no way to create, initialize, and add `n` items to a set in O(1) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not too fussy about the tolerance, then you can round each number to the closest multiple of tol/4.

You can then use a hash map, but when you add a number x, add floor(4x/tol), floor(4x/tol+1) and floor(4x/tol-1).

When you look up a number x, look up floor(4x/tol), floor(4x/tol+1) and floor(4x/tol-1).

You will certainly find a match within tol/2, and you may find a match within tol.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas I had (and by no means are these necessarily the best):

1.) Mask the lower N bits of the number to all 0's. For instance, if you want the tolerance to be approx. 1E-3, force the lower 10 bits of mantissa to 0 when adding. Do the same when checking.

One caveat of this approach is that real computers often do weird things to LSB's of mantissas when you're not looking. You store x = b00111111100000000000000000000000, and when you retrieve it you get 00111111100000000000000000000001, 001111110111111111111111111111111, etc. The reasons for this are many, but the bottom line is that it's still brittle. Anything that relies on float equality is brittle.

2.) Create a hashable data structure containing the different fields from an IEEE-754 float separately. Why do that? you ask. The reason is twofold:

A.) By using an object that isn't a float, you prevent the runtime from treating this number as a float. I know it shouldn't matter, but I've seen LSB's mangled so many times it obviously matters even if it's hard to say why. This overcomes one caveat with storing a multiple of tol/4 *as a float*. I like the idea of rounding a number to a multiple of tol. The only downside is that if you store the number as a float the runtime can still mangle LSBs, which is the original motivation for this question.

B.) You can store just the upper N MSB's of the mantissa - in other words, choose N such that 2**-N represents a relative tolerance you like.

This captures the idea of rounding to multiple of tol, but also doesn't tell the runtime and/or CPU that this is a float, thereby preventing LSB mangling.

Interested to hear other ideas, critiques, etc.

Comment: "You store x = b00111111100000000000000000000000, and when you retrieve it you get 00111111100000000000000000000001, 001111110111111111111111111111111" You then throw your computer in the <s>trash</s> recycle bin and buy a working one. Only broken computers do that. "Anything that relies on float equality is britte" Wrong, otherwise you won't be able to hash floating point numbers.

Comment: @n.m. Then I'd have to throw all of NASA's computers in the trash, which I would gladly do, but unfortunately I can't afford new ones :/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than another set, adjust meaning of "close".

Create a function that maps each finite `float` to an integer.

Mentally place every positive `float` in a list - sorted by value.  0.0 is at index 0 and `MAX_FLOAT` is at index `N`. (Likely-wise for negatives: `-MAX_FLOAT` to -0.0 maps to `-N` to 0.  [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Total-ordering_predicate)

To find if 2 `float` values are "close", subtract their indexes and compare to a tolerance.

This maintains the idea of *float* in *floating-point* numbers as the tolerance is a fixed integer in the index mapping domain, yet scales in the `float` domain.